# Class methods read different values of the same variable C++

Tags: c++, oop

My class has a variable of a user-defined type. I set this variable in one method of the class. When I try to get this variable from another method of the same class, the value is always 0, although the variable has not been changed anywhere else.

I really don't understand why this happens! Follwoing is a sample of my code:

myclass.h

```
typedef enum {
    ACTIVE   =  0,  
    SLEEP    =  1,  
    FINISHED =  2,  
    WAITING  =  3,
    KILLED   =  4
} Mode;


class MyClass
{
    public:
      void statusReceive(void);
      Mode getCurrentMode(void);

    private:
      Mode currentMode;
};
```

myclass.cpp

```
#include "myclass.h"

void MyClass::statusReceive(void)
{
    currentMode = (Mode)interpretMsg(&msg);
    printf("current Mode = %d\n", this->currentMode); // prints 4
}

Mode MyClass::getCurrentMode(void)
{
    printf("current Mode = %d\n", this->currentMode);   // prints 0
    return this->currentMode;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "myclass.h"

MyClass myclass;

void timerStart(std::function<void(void)> func, unsigned int interval)
{
    std::thread([func, interval]()
            { 
            while (true)
            { 
            auto x = std::chrono::steady_clock::now() + std::chrono::milliseconds(interval);
            func();
            std::this_thread::sleep_until(x);
            }
            }).detach();
}

int main(void)
{
    timerStart(std::bind(&MyClass::statusReceive, myclass), 10);
    Mode x = myclass.getCurrentMode();
    printf("Current Mode = %d\n", x); // prints 0
}
```

Comment: You mean `Mode x = myclass.getValue();` and what is `Mode`?

Comment: Missing parenthesis in your main: `Mode x = myclass.getValue();`

Comment: Thanks. I've fixed the missing parentheses. I just forgot to write them. I have them in my code

Comment: sounds like you need to break out your debugger

Comment: this code is correct, and we know its not your real failing code. We need to see that

Comment: here it is running https://ideone.com/4bkz4c

Comment: Is it really the posted code which fails, or you have simplified the real code (perhaps a bit too much) ?

Comment: This doesn’t address the problem, but you don’t need explicit values for those enumerators. Those values are the same as the defaults.

Comment: my guess is that you are setting one instance of myClass and reading a different instance

Comment: I've updated the code to be as close as possible to my code. My project is too large, but I've included everything related to my problem exactly as it is in my real code. Maybe then the problem is related to how I call the functions from main.cpp!!?

Comment: in each printf case add a print of `this` or `myclass`. I suspect you are setting one object and reading a different one.

Comment: @pm100 Thanks for your response. you mean in `myclass.cpp`? I already add `this->currentMode` to both `printf`s. How can I set one object while reading another one, while I only have one object?

Comment: You could print `this` in addition to the mode value. And you do have two objects. Out of `bind`, `function`, the lambda, and `thread`, someone creates an extra copy.

Comment: do `printf("current Mode = %d adr=%p \n", this->currentMode,this); ` and same thing in main (except use &myclass instead of `this`

Comment: Thanks for your helpful comments. I'll give feedback as soon as I have access to my workplace. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two problems with this code.

First, `std::bind` does a copy (or move) of all its arguments.  So the functor value returned from `bind` contains another `MyClass` object which was copy-constructed from the `myclass` object, and calls to that functor will only change the internal `MyClass`, not `myclass`.

You could use a reference-wrapper to specify using the same `MyClass` object:

```
timerStart(std::bind(&MyClass::statusReceive, std::ref(myclass)), 10);
```

or just switch to a lambda to call the member function on `myclass` directly:

```
timerStart([](){ myclass.statusReceive(); }, 10);
```

Second, you are modifying the `myclass.currentMode` object in one thread and reading it in another without any synchronization between the two operations.  This is a data race and undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks @aschepler for your answer. 
Unfortunately, I'll not have access to my work station, which is in the university, before Monday morning. I'll give you feedback as soon as I try your solution. Thanks again