# Class variable has default value in each function call?

Tags: c++, multithreading, oop

In `MyClass` there are two functions. `FuncA` sends a command to be executed while `FuncB` checks the progress in executing the command sent by `FunA`. As `FuncB` waits in a while loop until it makes sure the command was successfully executed, I call `FuncB` in a separate thread. The thread in which `FunA` is running should not wait in a while loop.

In **main.cpp**, there are two functions which run in two different threads. `execute` makes decisions and call `FunA` to send commands while `check` calls `FuncB` to check the made decisions has been executed.

As I don't want `execute` to send the same decision more than once, I first make sure that `FuncA` is not running and that `FuncB` has reset `funcInUse` to `false`.

**myclass.h**

```
class MyClass
{
    public:
        MyClass();
        void FuncA(float x, floaty, floatz);
        bool FuncB(void);
        bool IsFuncInUse(void);
        void QuitFuncA(void);

    private:
        bool funcInUse;
        bool _x;
        std::mutex mtx;
}
```

**myclass.cpp**

```
MyClass::MyClass()
{
   funcInUse = false;
}

void MyClass::FuncA(float x, float y, float z)
{
    if(funcInUse == true)
    {
        printf("FuncA already in use\n");
        return;
    }
    // Gaining the lock, so that no two threads call the function at the same time
   mtx.lock();
    funcInUse = true;
   mtx.unlock();

    printf("INSIDE FuncA()::: %d\n", funcInUse?1:0);
    printf("THIS FuncA() adr=%p \n", this);

   // DO STUFF
}

bool MyClass::FuncB(void)
{
   if(funcInUse == true)
   {
    printf("THIS ISPOSREACHED() adr=%p \n", this);

    // DO STUFF

    // Giving the lock back before returning
   mtx.lock();
    funcInUse = false;
   mtx.unlock();

   printf("Function is no more in use\n");
   }

   return true;
}

bool MyClass:IsFuncInUse(void)
{
    return isFuncInUse;
}

void MyClass:QuitFuncA(void)
{
   mtx.lock();
    funcInUse = false;
   mtx.unlock();
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
MyClass myClass;

void timerStart(std::function<void(void)> func, unsigned int interval)
{
    std::thread([func, interval]()
            { 
            while (true)
            { 
            auto x = std::chrono::steady_clock::now() + std::chrono::milliseconds(interval);
            func();
            std::this_thread::sleep_until(x);
            }
            }).detach();
}

void execute(void)
{
   if(/*some special condition*/)
   {
       myClass.QuitFuncA();
   }

    if(myClass.isFuncInUse() == false)
    {
        // USE THE FUNCTION
        myClass.FuncA();
    }
}

void check(void)
{
    if(myClass.isFuncInUse())
    {
        status = myClass.FuncB();
        printf("STATUS %d\n", status?true:false);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    timerStart(execute, 500);

    timerStart(check, 500);
}
```

**The problem is**: `FuncA` sets `funcInUse` to true in one iteration. In the next iteration, `funcInUse` is false again, although it was not been reset by `FuncB`. What may happen that resets `funcInUse` between the two iterations?

I tried printing `this` when calling the three functions in `MyClass` and all of them had the same address. I also tried to use bind with the class methods as I learned previously from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46994695/class-methods-read-different-values-of-the-same-variable-c) but it didn't work.

I tried to use mutex, semaphore and condition variables but I faced the problem that `FuncA` should gain the mutex while `FuncB` should release it after making sure the sent command has been executed (which is not allowed with mutex). And in one condition, a function in `MyClass` should reset `isFuncInUse`. Is there a better way to synchronize between the two methods than using `funcInUse` variable?

Thank you

Comment: The code, as you show it, should not build. Don't rewrite code into the question, *copy-paste* it.

Comment: As for your problem, `funcInUse` is *uninitialized* when you check it in `FuncA` and `FuncB`. That means its value is *indeterminate* and you will have [*undefined behavior*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). You need to actually *initialize* it, with a constructor.

Comment: As a side question: is there any specific reason you are not using any of the many functionalities offered by c++11 [thread support library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread) as mutex, condition variables and such?

Comment: In the code you posted, you never actually invoke `FuncA`

Comment: `funcInUse` needs to be a `std::atomic<bool>` *or* protected by a `std::mutex` or similar, since it is being accessed and both read and written from multiple threads. Failure to do so results in a data race, which is Undefined Behaviour - which means your program is meaningless. Beware; multi-threading is *hard* to get right!

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I've tried different things you mentioned in the comments and updated my question and code. Still have the same problem